# Meta-analysis of change scores

Tags: meta-analysis

I am helping to publish a meta-analysis conducted by a student. The analysis has calculated a standardised mean difference (SMD) by comparing the post-intervention scores of the intervention and control groups.

However, many of the primary studies had very small samples that produced what appear to be large baseline imbalances between the intervention and control groups. I would like to correct for these if possible, but simply calculating the SMD using the change scores does not seem to be recommended by the Cochrane Collaboration.

I have read that using ANCOVA is preferred here, but because I don't have access to the original study data, just the published group pre-post differences and SDs, I don't believe this is possible.

Am I right about this last point? If so, what should I do?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Are these RCTs or CCTs? If RCTs then you can just use the post-treatment means.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the change scores if that is all you have.